# Why do firefox-based browsers react incorrectly to window.screenX/Y in my code?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, firefox

I'm building a home website in which the window will create an illusion of transparency even when windowed and moved around in real time and I'm trying to use `screenX` and `screenY` for the cause (I should note that `screenLeft` and `screenTop` react the same).

In Google Chrome it reacts well, although the values are a bit weird (moving windowed windows on left edge will return `-25`)
In Firefox the function always returns `0`, unless windowed, in that case it returns constant `25`.
In Librewolf, the target browser, I always get constant `0`. Letterboxing seems to have no effect.
Why is it that way, why only on Chrome and how can I fix this issue? I found no relevant fixes on this topic.
(If it's relevant, which I doubt, I'm on linux with wayland)

The code in which I'm trying to utilize the functions:

```js
const canvas = document.getElementById("background");
const context = canvas.getContext("2d");

var pozadi = new Image();
pozadi.src = https://placehold.co/2240x1217;
var hod_x = window.screenX;
var hod_y = window.screenY;

pozadi.onload = function() {
  context.drawImage(pozadi, hod_x, hod_y, 2240, 1217, 0, 0, 2240, 1217);
}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0px
}
```

```html
<canvas id="background" width="2240px" height="1217px"></canvas>
```

Comment: Please update the snippet I made you with images from or example https://placehold.co/

Comment: What is "minimalised" supposed to mean here?

Comment: My apologies, I meant windowed. I fixed the issue,

Comment: Works fine for me on plain Firefox 123 on macOS. Maybe LibreWolf has some finger-printing protection that will temper with these values?

Comment: I also expect LibrwWolf to have similar protection, but I'm getting the issues I mentioned in Firefox as well. Perhaps an end-user issue?